# Woocommerce - Dynamic Link to The Most Recently Added Product

Tags: woocommerce-offtopic

Is there any way to have a dynamic link which directs the user to the most recently added product?

I'd like to send out automated newsletters that simply have this link so that whenever its clicked on users can go to the newest item added.

I can't seem to find this anywhere googling around

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

This code will do what you want. It will redirect to the latest product added if you add `?latest_product` to your site's URL. So the dynamic link would be `http://example.com/?latest_product`

```
function wpse_274155_redirect_latest_product() {
    // If URL has ?latest_product query string.
    if ( isset( $_GET['latest_product'] ) ) {
        // Get latest product.
        $latest_products = get_posts( array(
            'posts_per_page' => 1,
            'post_type'      => 'product',
            'no_found_rows'  => true,
            'orderby'        => 'date',
            'order'          => 'DESC',
        ) );

        // Make sure product exists.
        if ( isset( $latest_products[0] ) ) {
            // Redirect to product.
            wp_redirect( get_permalink( $latest_products[0] ) );
            exit();
        }
    }
}
add_action( 'template_redirect', 'wpse_274155_redirect_latest_product' );
```